# Specifying keyword type on String field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I started using hibernate-search-elasticsearch(5.8.2) because it seemed easy to integrate it maintains elasticsearch indices up to date without writing any code. It's a cool lib, but I'm starting to think that it has a very small set of the elasticsearch functionalities implemented. I'm executing a query with a painless script filter which needs to access a String field, which type is 'text' in the index mapping and this is not possible without enabling field data. But I'm not very keen on enabling it as it consumes a lot of heap memory. Here's what elasticsearch team suggests to do in my case:

[Fielddata documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html)

> Before you enable fielddata, consider why you are using a text field for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It usually doesn’t make sense to do so.
>
> A text field is analyzed before indexing so that a value like New York can be found by searching for new or for york. A terms aggregation on this field will return a new bucket and a york bucket, when you probably want a single bucket called New York.
>
> Instead, you should have a text field for full text searches, and an unanalyzed keyword field with doc_values enabled for aggregations, as follows:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way to do it with the hibernate-search annotations. Can someone tell me if this is possible or I have to migrate to the vanilla elasticsearch lib and not using any wrappers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the current version of Hibernate Search, you need to create a different field for that (e.g. you can't have different flavors of the same field). Note that that's what Elasticsearch is doing under the hood anyway.

```
@Field(analyzer = "your-text-analyzer") // your default full text search field with the default name
@Field(name="myPropertyAggregation", index = Index.NO, normalizer = "keyword")
@SortableField(forField = "myPropertyAggregation")
private String myProperty;
```

It should create an unanalyzed field with doc values. You then need to refer to the `myPropertyAggregation` field for your aggregations.

Note that we will expose much more Elasticsearch features in the API in the future Search 6. In Search 5, the APIs are designed with Lucene in mind and we couldn't break them.